# product description text displays above website when in shop page

Tags: html, escaping

Product description text appears above and outside of website. It is seen when in the shop page. When I look at the site from my smart phone, and also while visiting site from the back office.
http://marketingmagics.com

Answer (score 1):

Your product descriptions contain html code which is inserted into description meta tags without proper escaping. The resulting meta tags look like this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p class="p1">100% Natural Anti-Ageing Face Cream with Marine Collagen, Elastin &amp; Essential Proteins - Anti-Wrinkle Cream to Repair, Restore, Rebuild &amp; Rejuvenate Skin</p>" />
```

The problematic part is `<p class="p1">` which contains unescaped quotes.

I suspect that a filter like `wpautop` is being applied to the description, maybe because the excerpt is being inserted as description in a way that filters are being applied.

You should check that there is no html code in the fields where you enter the descriptions.

You should also check why the content inserted as description is not being properly escaped, probably this is an issue within a plugin for SEO, which should be discussed with the responsible developer.

Comment: Thank you JHoffman, I kept looking at the above web text and noticed it was generated by the short description I copied and pasted from Amazon.

Comment: So by deleting the pasted from Amazon and writing the description myself that fixed the problem, thank you again for you help.